# Converting data coming from database using model mutator convert the key value in Normal data I mean it will not show html tags

Tags: php, laravel-5

** How it is possible to not show tags of html  in Android api i am using model mutator for this **
`{!! !!}` By this we can convert in blade file but how it is possible in mutator to send api response for android

Answer (score 0):

As per the Laravel docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

You can append data to JSON responses by adding the property `$appends` to your model. For example:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
     protected $appends = ['no_html'];


     public function getNoHtmlAttribute() {
         // Your mutator code...
     }
}
```